# HTML Image and PhpStorm

Tags: html, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

Cannot resolve file 'logo.png' - said the HTML

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" width="314" height="70">
```

The HTML keeps saying it can't find it, but it works. Meanwhile, if I tell it that it's in public/logo.png, then its a broken image.

If this is a feature, how can I turn off this markup. If It works, I don't want to have warnings. If it can be done better, tell me, I'll fix it and again - no markups like errors or sort of.

Comment: Please share more details - if "The HTML keeps saying it can't find it", how is that related to PhpStorm?

Comment: What is the absolute path of the directory that hosts your images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You must right-click on "public" directory in PHPStorm
- Select "Mark Directory as" -> "Resource Root"
- Profit